# How to make Diacritics be available with single key press on German keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

On the standard German keyboard layout in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 Diacritic keys are handled as modifiers so that you first press the Diacritic key (e.g. <kbd>`</kbd>) and then the key for the base letter (e.g. <kbd>a</kbd>) to get the actual wanted letter <kbd>à</kbd> which is not available by separate key on the keyboard.

As a programmer this is odd as in [Markup](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code) (used here in StackExchange) and some programming languages (e.g. [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)) the separated Diacritic letter <kbd>`</kbd> is used very often. To get it you need to press <kbd>`</kbd> key twice or first <kbd>`</kbd> and then <kbd>Space</kbd>.

**Keeping the German layout, how can I get the separated Diacritic letter <kbd>`</kbd> available with a single keypress using its key on the keyboard?**

Answer (score 2):

There are several variants of German keyboard layouts. One of them, which may be useful for you, is the *German (dead acute)* layout, where the <kbd>`</kbd> (grave/backtick) symbol is not a "dead" key.

The file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` includes the following comment on the *German (dead acute)* layout:

> modify the basic German layout to have only acute as dead keys (ASCII
>   grave, tilde and circumflex are needed as spacing characters in many
>   programming languages and text formatters)